# Hibernate doesn't seem to see change on De-serialized object

Tags: hibernate, serialization, jms, deserialization

I asked a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211887/hibernate-one-to-many-mapping-doesnt-saved-upon-update?noredirect=1#comment33731877_22211887), but now I narrowed down the problem.

So to sum up: I have Person object with several phone numbers which were saved and persisted to the database.

Fine. I then made changes to some of the phone number, **serialized the entire Person object, sent it over jms to some back end service,** de-serialized it there and saved it.
It seems that because of the serialize-deserialize, the changes on the set of PhoneNumbers don't get picked up by Hibernate.

```
class Person
{
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
   @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN,org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
private Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new HashSet<PhoneNumber>();

//.... omitted ....
}

class PhoneNumber
{      
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private Person person;

  //... omitted ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is expected. When you serialize the object and send it over JMS, you're likely bypassing the proxy that hibernate created over it and instead working directly with your class.  LIkewise, moving an object over JMS will send it outside of JPA's context, so it won't be able to track the entity any longer.

You can probably do a fetch, merge to refresh the object.  I can't say I'd recommend dealing with an entity in this manner though.